# Resolving undeclared Indentifer from Class (Part 2)

Tags: iphone, xcode

I want to created and populate an Array in a class and then use the content in the array in the main program... As an example I'll use a list of names of the US States...

This is an update on the original question that is halfway resolved and has been contented for clarity so you can see the code properly.

ArrayStates.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@interface ArrayStates : NSObject
@end
```

ArrayStates.m

```
#import "ArrayStates.h"
@interface ArrayStates() { NSMutableArray *listOfStates; }
@implementation ArrayStates
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    //---initialize the array---
    listOfStates = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    //---add items---
    [listOfStates addObject:@"ALABAMA"];

    [listOfStates addObject:@"WYOMING"];
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
@end
```

This is updated code from the previous Question but it still generates a Missing end error on the implementation line, the void wants a . after method prototype and you still can't reference the object in the main program.

I believe altering the ordering if the interface and implementation differentiates whether the array can be accessed within or outside the class (thanks to iHungry for that).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// in ArrayStates.h
@interface ArrayStates : NSObject
@property NSMutableArray *listOfStates;
@end

// in ArrayStates.m
@implementation ArrayStates
@synthesize listOfStates;
//...
-(void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    listOfStates = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
}
@end

// in some other class
ArrayStates *states = [[ArrayStates alloc] init];
NSLog(@"%@", states.listOfStates);
```

Comment: Fantastic - that gets rid of the comelier errors in ArraySates but I'm still no being able to access listOfStates in the main program. I have  included #import "ArrayStates.h" at the top of the .m

Comment: You have to initialize your array. You need an instance of the "ArrayStates" (with alloc-init), and then you can access its properties. The properties that are accessible from outside must be declared in the .h file. See the edit.

Answer (score 2):

Create a property like Mundi said in the .h, and then just import the ArrayStates.h where ever you need to access the array.  You can then make an instance of class ArrayStates, (create an object and alloc-init), and then use that object to access its listOfStates property.

Comment: Done, I was wondering what the linkage should be. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In the viewDidLoad method, you must call super first.
By the way, your ArrayStates class is a subclass of NSObject so its method viewDidLoad will not gonna be called!

Comment: Unfortunately the compiler doesn't like the [super viewDidLoad]; line and gives a "no visible ATinterface for 'NSObject' declares the selector 'viewDidLoad'".

Comment: Do I need to add '@'property and '@'synthesise to ArrayStates? From previous advice I was told that the Class is fine but it's still not working with listOfStates not found...

Comment: Point taken, so I need to make it a sub-class of tableview controller?

Comment: In your case you can populate your array in the init method and not in the viewDidLoad method.